# JSTL - How to use a possessive apostrophe in a string?

Tags: jstl, apostrophe

```
 <c:choose> 
    <c:when test="${place=='Bob's Car'}">
    <c:set var="place" value="Truck"/>
    </c:when>
 </c:choose>
```

Code is not working because of apostrophe from " Bob's ". Is there any solution?

Comment: I do not remember without IDE, but have you tried `\'`? Or doubling? Or mix with double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Try use \ this make java understand a simple apostrophe in your expression language.

For me run!